# WebRTC VideoRendererGui

Tags: android, webrtc

I only want to **send** video from an Android WebRTC client. Do I need a GLSurfaceView.Renderer like the one obtained via VideoRendererGui?  And if not, then what would you pass for the eglContext part of this:

```
PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(
  Object context, boolean initializeAudio, boolean initializeVideo,
  boolean vp8HwAcceleration, Object renderEGLContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already found a solution ? My use case was similar to your's. I guess, you already explored how [VideoCapturerAndroid.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/4765070b8d6f024509c717c04d9b708750666927/talk/app/webrtc/java/src/org/webrtc/VideoCapturerAndroid.java) library, specially "startCaptureOnCameraThread" function was implemented in webRTC, and found your solution. Just in case if you still having problems with it; Yes, you can sure escape creating a local egl surface renderer if you don't need to, and can just pass null for the fifth parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I pass null on eglContext. I've checked the value of `VideoRendererGui.getEGLContext()` and it's `null`. So if you pass `null` is not a problem, audio/video/data streaming works great!